# Using Selenium to download a segment of a JW Player Live Stream

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a python script using selenium to download 60s (arbitrary) of a live video feed (through a JW Player). A screen recording of sorts would be an acceptable solution (if limited to the frame the video is on) but a straight download would be preferable.

The live stream is behind a login, so I have a script which logs in and tries to load the video.

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://magicseaweed.com/account/login/?dest=%2FLive-Whitesands-Webcam%2F245%2F")

email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msw-js-user-login-tab"]/form/div[2]/input')
email.clear()
email.send_keys("***@gmail.com")

pwd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msw-js-user-login-tab"]/form/div[3]/input')
pwd.clear()
pwd.send_keys("******")
pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msw-js-player245-stream"]').click()

driver.close()
```

I'm not sure why but

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msw-js-player245-stream"]').click()
```

doesn't start playing the video even though I was expecting it to.

The xpath is the a `div` containing

```html
<video class="jw-video jw-reset" src="blob:https://magicseaweed.com/91b9d409-5ebf-4b93-a38a-8e6f0625f954"></video>
```

but it also doesn't work by choosing the xpath of the above.

So currently, I have the video on screen but can't start it playing and am not sure how to download or screen record 60s of it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with the `xpath`. I have noticed that the `xpath`s given by the Selenium IDE are generally wrong, so I suggest using inspect and copy to get the `xpath`s instead.